# Conditional formatting doesn't update when I delete a row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So I have a sheet which has a conditional format something like:

```
=$R1<>$R2
```

Which applies to the entire range of A1:C1000.

Now let's say I have the cells:

```
R09 = "ha" 
R10 = "ha" 
R11 = "hi"
```

Which means the condition is true and the entire row will be formatted. So it does and it all works great.

But now the problem arises when I delete row R10 then the conditional all gets broken and doesn't do anything. It still does work for other rows but the new row R10 with value "hi" doesn't get formatted anymore. (Deleting other rows where the value is the same gives no problems. Adding rows neither) 
When I look at the formula it says

```
=#REF!<>$R11
```

Now I already tried pressing F9 and made sure that events are enabled. I also tried to use INDIRECT

```
=INDIRECT($R10)<>INDIRECT($R11)
```

But that didn't work at all.

How should I proceed? I can't impossible keep changing the rownumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,0)<>OFFSET(A1,-1,0)
```

This will look a row above the current row for the comparison.  I would think this is deletion resistant.

Comment: Funny, I tested that out before posting.  When adding the formula, make sure cell A1 is selected.  This works in Excel 2010.

Comment: I'm working in Excel 2010 too. I also have the responding cell selected. In my case =OFFSET(R11,0,0)<>OFFSET(R11,-1,0). I also like the process behind it very clever. Now just getting it to work.

Comment: Ah got it! The seperators should be ; and not , However I'm getting the strange formatting ever. It's like it's just coloring some cells at random. But that could be my fault so thank you!